# Returning a struct fails to properly copy data members

Tags: c++, crosstool-ng

I'm cross-compiling a program for a raspberry pi 3. Below is a minimal working example of something I've written that show's an issue I'm running into.

I'm trying to fill a struct and then return that struct from a function. Importantly, one of the members of the struct is a double, which is initialized from a string that is an integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Thing {
  size_t a{};
  double b{};
};

double fill_b(){
  std::string s = "1234";
  double b = std::stod(s);
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
  return b;
};

Thing get_thing(){
  Thing thing;
  thing.a = 1;
  thing.b = fill_b();
  std::cout << thing.b << std::endl;
  return thing;
};

int main(){
  Thing thing = get_thing();
  std::cout << "A: " << thing.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << "B: " << thing.b << std::endl;
}
```

When I run this, `A` is correct, but `B` is some random number, even though when it is set it is correct. Repeated runs give the same numbers. Also, compiling this and running on my host computer, an m1 mac, gives a correct result.

```
1234
1234
A: 1
B: 2.11371e-314
```

At first I thought that maybe the implicitly defined copy constructor is bad and changed Thing to this:

```
struct Thing {
  size_t a;
  double b;

  Thing() : a(), b() {}
  Thing(const Thing& other) : a(other.a), b(other.b) {}
};
```

And now I get this for output. Repeated runs produce the same numbers.

```
1234
1234
A: 1
B: -5.48613e+303
```

So that doesn't seem to be it. My guess is that I possibly setup my cross compiling toolchain incorrectly, but I don't know how to verify that.

*Edit*:

I don't know why I didn't think of this until now. I compiled this on the pi and that worked, so it definitely is the toolchain.

Comment: The shown code does not seem to be a [mcve]. It looks like you compile and link 2 translation units with different compiler settings with different `sizeof(double)` values.

Comment: It's really odd you're defining a non-standard constructor for a `struct` when you could define a normal one and your code would make a lot more sense at a glance. Define `Thing::Thing()` instead of this awkward `get_thing()` thing.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your cross-compiler settings, too, as some ARM modes have to use "soft" floating points.

Comment: @273K what do you mean? This is the one file that I compile. The second code snippet is something that replaces the content of the struct from the first snippet.

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure what you mean by that either. This isn't a nonstandard constructor, it's a function that fills up data members of a struct. It's a POD class.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest making `Thing::Thing()` do what `get_thing()` does, as it belongs in the class, and as it constructs, it's a type fo constructor.

Comment: @tadman as far as the settings go, I built using crosstools-NG, and my process for that is defined in the readme here: https://github.com/K20shores/PiStats

Comment: @tadman Your suggestion is not related to the problem that I am seeing; that is your preference for using OOP and not constructive in answering this question, though I do appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: The reason I mention it is because we see a lot of C++ questions here, and the more time we have to spend puzzling through your particular way of doing things, the less time we can focus on the problem at hand. It might also produce different results, as it'll manipulate `this` in place, vs. employing a potentially broken copy constructor.

Comment: You should stub into the `Thing(const Thing& other)` implementation to see if anything weird is going on with `b`, or `other.b` for that matter.

Comment: @tadman I understand your concern that I may be doing things differently, but that is not related to the issue that I am seeing.

Comment: A key part of debugging is removing anything unusual whenever possible, and then if the bug *persists*, dig deeper. One thing to try is make `get_thing()` use `new Thing` instead and return a pointer, hence no copy constructor. Does it still persist?

Comment: @tadman changing the return type to a pointer gives the same result. Inside `get_thing`, the value of `b` is printed properly, but in `main`, I get some other number.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to get to the bottom of with a debugger where you can step through, so consider that. A closer look at the memory will be very educational. It's also worth trying `fill_b()` directly inside of `main()`.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate your attempts at helping me. This definitely seems to be an issue with cross compiling. If I figure out what I did wrong there, I'll drop that information here.

Comment: I'll admit it's a weird one, but I'd love to know the answer to this mystery too.

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure what I finally did right, but it was definitely a toolchain issue. Whatever changes I made today made this pass. A change that I made was to ensure I set `CMAKE_AR` and `CMAKE_RANLIB` to my toolchain binaries, which I hadn't been doing before, but there were other changes as well. I am not sure what was the final factor. It still may be wrong, but I won't know until I continue doing more things.